# Styling and positioning a lightning-modal

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-modal

Used a popover blueprint for this look but I'm not benefitting from the built-in open/close and faded background functionality of a **lightning-moda**l....
[image]

Is there a way to customize the **lightning-modal** to:

1. Precisely position the modal relative to an element
2. Set the width and height explicitly instead of rely on variants of small, medium, and large

I can add the nubbin easily enough and live with lightning-modal close button being outside of the box but I could not find a way to control the position and precise sizing with styling hooks.

If this can't be done with the **lightning-modal**, I will continue down the path I'm on to create a custom modal. Was hoping to not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, this is not supported. The only supported styling hooks are detailed within the SLDS documentation for [Modals](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/#Styling-Hooks-Overview). Given your use case, it doesn't look like the modal component will be useful unfortunately.